# Extract rows based on values using UDF in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe in the below format. Trying to extract the rows when values are present in any of the columns in the below list.

columns_list = [column2, column3]

df:

```
   column1       column2        column3
   abc           def             ghi
   abc1                           
   abc2              
   abc3          jkl
   abc4                          mno
```

result_df

```
   column1       column2        column3
   abc           def             ghi       
   abc3          jkl
   abc4                          mno
```

I tried with the below UDF:

```
def valuesAny(string, array):
  if len(string) == 0:
    return False
  else:
    return True
```

Not sure on how to pass the rows as such to UDF. Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the required operation without needing a UDF by [`concatenating`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat.html?highlight=concatenate) the columns after [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html?highlight=coalesce) and then applying a [`length`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.length.html?highlight=length) check on them.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("abc", "def", "ghi",),
        ("abc1", None, None,),
        ("abc2", None, None,),
        ("abc3", "jkl", None,),
        ("abc4", None, "mno",), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("column1", "column2", "column3",))



column_list = ["column2", "column3"]

concatenated_column = F.concat(*[F.coalesce(F.col(c), F.lit("")) for c in column_list])

df.where(F.length(F.trim(concatenated_column)) > 0).show(truncate=False)

"""
+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|
+-------+-------+-------+
|abc    |def    |ghi    |
|abc3   |jkl    |null   |
|abc4   |null   |mno    |
+-------+-------+-------+
"""
```

If you want to make use of the UDF then you can pass in the concatednated expression to the UDF and do the length check inside.

```py
@F.udf
def valuesAny(string: str) -> bool:
  if len(string) == 0:
    return False
  else:
    return True

df.where(valuesAny(concatenated_column) == True).show()
```